# How to map property of type `Object` with different datatypes to a corresponding classtype?

Tags: c#, automapper

I have two classes:

```
public class A{
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("type1", typeof(XMLItemType1), IsNullable=true)]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("type2", typeof(XMLItemType2), IsNullable=true)]
public object Item { get; set; }
}

public class B{
public object Item { get; set; }
}
```

Mapping is created as follows:

```
AutoMapper.Mapper.CreateMap<A, B>()
.ForMember(domainObject => domainObject.Item ,
metaData => metaData.MapFrom(xmlObject => xmlObject.Item ));


AutoMapper.Mapper.CreateMap<XMLItemType1, XMLObjectType1>();
AutoMapper.Mapper.CreateMap<XMLItemType2, XMLObjectType2>();

AutoMapper.Mapper.Map<A, B>(data);
```

But the output property of B class `Item` is of type `XMLItemType1` instead of `XMLObjectType1`.

How can I make sure that after mapping `Item` is of type `XMLObjectType1` or `XMLObjectType2`?